# Adding and removing shopping cart items stored in session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For an assignment I have to create a shopping cart, I've opted to use Session to persist the cart items as they're added, but how do I allow the user to remove items or update quantity?

This is the code-behind for the shopping cart page after the user has clicked "Add to Cart", the product data is pulled from the Request data, inserted into an object, and then added to the session. The contents of the session are then displayed in a gridview but this doesnt seem to create anyway for me to manage the contents (ie. add a remove button, quanity input)

```vb
Partial Class ShoppingCart
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Create a new product from the request data'
        Dim ProductToAdd As New Product
        ProductToAdd.productPrice = Request.QueryString("Price")
        ProductToAdd.productTitle = Request.QueryString("Title")
        ProductToAdd.productQuantity = 1

        'Check if the session exists'
        If Session("Cart") Is Nothing Then
            Session("Cart") = New List(Of Product)
        End If

        'Add the product object to the session'
        Session("Cart").Add(ProductToAdd)

        'Update the UI'
        With Session("Cart")
            GridView1.DataSource = Session("Cart")
        End With

        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
End Class
```

item to add

[image]

shoppingcart page

[image]

Comment: All that code is on Page_Load, not a button-click. Move it all to a separate method and call it as needed, on page load, on button click, etc. Create a similar (but different) method for removing an item and call as needed.

Comment: I don't think `With Session` is required.